# Bootstrap Columns not working on toggling hide/show

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm Using Bootstrap 4.3.1,  and I'm trying to toggle between 2 divs, one shows and the other hides.

Everything's working fine except inside the divs is bootstrap cols that don't work on the div that was originally hidden.  These seems to have to do with the css to hide the 1st div (display:none;)

So - form1 starts out hidden and form2 is visible.
Click the button and they toggle.

This works but form1 shows like
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah

instead of in 3 colums (col-md-4)
blah blah    |    blah blah    |   blah blah

Here is my code:

```js
$('.togglebutton').on('click', function (e) {
        var frm = $(this).closest('.frm');
        frm.find('.form1').toggle(200, 'swing');
        frm.find('.form2').toggle(200, 'swing');
        });
```

```css
.hidden {display:none !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha256-D9AvR0EzkNZoWZVSvI3ch+uf/Z5izrIpcbsykVphwPU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" integrity="sha256-dARYuC3pd0wa/7R4Hkt/sR2zfLHCgbnVAQ2sPwhNe0A=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row frm">  
        <div class="row form1 hidden">  
            <div class="col-md-4">  
       1blah blah  
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       1blah blah
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       1blah blah
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row form2">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        2blah blah
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       2blah blah
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       2blah blah
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success togglebutton" type="submit">Edit</button>
```

I have tried this method above
I have tried using bootstrap's '.d-none' instead of '.hidden'
using 'collapse' with jquery
(these divs are part of a list of many on the page so the regular collapse would not work)

In all these cases the toggle worked fine by the css on the top form does not work (bottom form works fine).

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `row` class to each form div.

N.P 1: i've changed column size to small just to fit the snippet size, You don't have to that.

N.P 2: I've changes JS code to make the toggle button work in the example.

```js
$(".togglebutton").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".form1").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".form2").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
```

```css
.hidden {display:none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="togglebutton">TOGGLE ME!!</button>
<div class="frm">  
        <div class="form1 row hidden">  
            <div class="col-sm-4">  
       blah blah1  
       </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       blah blah1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       blah blah1
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form2 row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        blah blah2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       blah blah2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       blah blah2 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It should render in 3 columns - not 3 rows.  I am having the same issue above, the code snippet doesn't appear to be working right

Comment: It's already rendering 3 columns, Try to expand it to fullpage

Comment: sorry, missed the full page - - but I believe that is the second div (above I relabeled the blah blahs).  Its the hidden div- that when it opens does not show the columns.  I am having trouble above with making the button work right

Comment: So the question now is how to make the button work not with columns right?

Comment: on my end the button works fine so I have to figure what I am doing wrong in the example...probably a typo somewhere

Comment: Check the edited answer, I've edited JS code to make the button work in the example

Comment: @Kareeem yes yours works - let me try it on my end .. thanks

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if you find that it solved the problem